# Do I need a SMTP server for my domain to receive email?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, gmail-imap

my domain has a domain extension that since my country is not supported by Google Apps I can't use that lovely GApps services for that domain.

I need free email service of GApps the most, so I decided to give a go to "Send mail as" feature of a regular Gmail account and add my domain emails to that personal Gmail.

I have a question:

**Do I need a SMTP server for my domain to receive email from others?**

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a SMTP server that is configured to accept mail for your domain – and you must configure your domain's "MX" records to point to that server. (It's not necessary to configure it in Gmail.)